# gradle maven plugin - how to customise maven upload's archive name

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-plugin, build.gradle

In a gradle script, I am able to customise the name of a built WAR archive by adding the following line:

`war.archiveName = "${war.baseName}##${war.version}.${war.extension}"`

This line would cause a generated WAR to be named something like this:

`project-name##1.0.1.war`

instead of

`project-name-1.0.1.war`

However, when the WAR file is then uploaded to a maven repository (using the maven deployer task), the WAR file is uploaded using the default archive name `project-name-1.0.1.war` and not `project-name##1.0.1.war`.

Is there a simple means to specify to the maven deployer how the archive name should be named when uploaded?

I know you can override classifiers, etc quite easily but, how about the archive name itself?

Thanks in advance,
PM

Comment: I would expect that you can't do that otherwise you will break the defined way how a Maven repository works. A maven repository is based on defined naming schema's.

Comment: Hello @khmarbaise, thanks for your input. If this is the definitive case, then we won't bother renaming WAR file names in our gradle scripts. I'll wait to see if somebody else can confirm this... Do you want to post your comment as a potential answer? If what you are saying is correct, then I'll accept your answer as final. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a maven repository you can't change the names of the deployed artifacts otherwise it would break the whole definition of a maven repository which is based on naming schemas.

```
groupId/artifactId/version/
```

For example:

```
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.10/

GroupId: org.apache.maven.plugins
ArtifactId: maven-dependency-plugin
Version: 2.10
```

The artifacts itself will be named like:

```
artifact-version[-classifier].type
```

If you would change the name of the deployed artifacts how would you find them later without knowing the name which has been used.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer @khmarbaise and thanks for explaining the reasoning as to why it is not possible.